# Round Up Float column to next number with a multiple of 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Currently I have a column defined as a float(ex 16.98) I need to be able to take the value and find the next highest multiple of 5.

Examples...

```
Value 16.98           Should Return 17.00  
Value 10.46           Should Return 10.50    
Value  9.11           Should Return  9.15  
Value  8.10           Should Return  8.10  
Value  18.65          Should Return 18.65
```

Notice that if is is a multiple of 5 then it should return itself.

Comment: Which db engine?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Format((ceiling(cast(unitprice*100 as int)/5.0)*5.0)/100.0, 'g18')
From table
```

Comment: This did't work with a number that I have which is 39.62  this returned 45.00   I need it to return 39.65.

Comment: Updated the query @Kd5490

Answer (score 1):

If You are using MySql try this:

```
SELECT (ceil(cast(val*100 as signed)/5.0)*5.0)/100.0 from tbl;
```

`CAST` inside `CEIL` is very helpful - it eliminates rounding error.

[Here is Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gJdE1TMnhFt8ER5HuWzCGS/0#&togetherjs=cpEPO1ElEd)

In SQL SERVER:

```
SELECT (ceiling(cast(val*100 as int)/5.0)*5.0)/100.0 from tbl;
```

Where `tbl` contains values to transform.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
CEILING(16.98 * 20) / 20,
CEILING(10.46 * 20) / 20,
CEILING(9.11 * 20) / 20,
CEILING(8.10 * 20) / 20,
CEILING(18.65 * 20) / 20
```

So the query would look like:

```
SELECT CEILING(yourColumn * 20) / 20 AS Result FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Nice and easy :D